# PHP IDE to suit my needs for Win 7

Tags: php, ide

I've been battling with several IDE's so far without much success, so I decided it would be ask someone wiser. I'd love one to have these features:

1. Fast code completion;
2. Completion for HTML (with tags and tags' content), CSS and, preferably, jQuery;
3. Debugger which can work with WampServer installation;
4. Completion for native PHP commands as well
5. <s>Shortcut to go to a file in the current project/workspace</s> (like Ctrl+Shift+O in Netbeans) --> What I meant here is that a shortcut to open a window, where you can type beginning of a file name and it will show you all matching files in project; so a way to navigate the project with keyboard only.

I have already tried some of IDE's:
**Netbeans**:

- It is slow, really slow. The slowest IDE of them all I believe
- Debugger had issues and overall I failed to make it work
- You can barely customize auto-formatting (at least in the way I'd like to customize it) - you can either disable it or live with it
- I am using it right now but strive to change it!

**Eclipse PDT**

- Kinda slowish, though faster than Netbeans
- There was no code hinting for native PHP commands @_@
- After restarting IDE, the Debugger decided to stop adding ?X-DEBUGwhatever stuff to links and it stopped working as result
- Subclipse didn't work!

**Nusphere PHP Edit**

- Fast and shiny, good for my netbook, but there is no "Go to file" command
- No JS hinting

Komodo and PHPDesigner 7 were disqualified for some reasons I can't really remember now but they were severe.
I tested a wide variety of IDE's but there is a real lot of them and pretty difficult to test them all, which is why I'd appreciate some input about one which fits all the above specified needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good PHP IDE, preferably free or cheap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap). Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ide+cheap+free). With the list you give, there is not that much left to try in terms of full fledged IDEs. Maybe [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) will suit you.

Comment: There is a go to file in Nusphere but it's in the tab title of the file. The option is "Locate file in Workspace", don't thik there is a short cut but if you find one tell me please :)

Comment: @Gordon - I know there are lots of similar questions, and I went through many of them trying to find something which works well for me, and only after realizing I didn't make any progress I decided to ask. Plus most IDEs are big files, and it takes loads of time for me to download them (my max download = 32KBytes/s). PHPStorm looks interesting, I am going to give it a try.   @AntonioCS: I have phrased myself incorrectly, that's not exactly the feature I had in mind :).

Comment: @Maurycy there is nothing wrong with wanting to find the perfect IDE for one's needs. And you did well by pointing out what you are looking for and which IDEs can be ruled out already. However, the linked question is almost canonical as of now. It contains three pages of IDEs to look at, including all mentioned below so far. Basically, the features you ask for are common to all full fledged IDEs, so any answers that could possibly be given here will be duplicate answers and that's just clutter then. I am just doing housekeeping here.

Comment: @Gordon I understand and I can't really say anything more on my defense. Well, maybe aside from the fact, that I haven't before noticed PHPStorm (must have somehow missed it while reading and/or skimming various IDE threads), so at least that's one good thing about it :)

Comment: @Maurycy you dont have to defend yourself. Your question would be a good one if it wasnt for the linked one. It's well phrased and you clearly put some effort into it. I am not blaming you. If anything, I am blaming the users who answer it despite seeing it's a duplicate (not that they would have to agree with me on that). Maybe I am just having a bad day today. It's just that I consider it community duty to find and close duplicates (at least when they are pretty obvious ones) instead of repwhoring on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough I decided to settle for Aptana 3 Beta. Though lots of features don't work it is awfully quick and I love the antialiased font. Thanks to all for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Consider vim.  It's painful at first, but it does meet all of your requirements, unless you also have a (as of yet unspoken) requirement for a Graphical User Interface.

1. Fast Code Completion: Fastest I've ever encountered, C-x C-o
2. Yes, Yes, and Probably.
3. vim can use xdebug to get this functionality. [How to set up on linux.](http://tech.blog.box.net/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/)
4. Yes.
5. :o supports tabbed completion even.

Comment: I don't think I can get used to Vim, I tried twice (three times counting my attempt now). Maybe if someone knowledgeable in it was standing next to me and explaining everything I would be able to start using it. But no for vim from me, unfortunately :(.

Answer (score 1):

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is a relatively new contender in the IDE scene by the people who make IDEA and Resharper. I can't say it's blazingly fast, but it's geared specifically toward PHP and has a lot of nice features. I feel it is a considerable improvement over Netbeans or Eclipse.

You might want to try the [pre-release](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP;jsessionid=A662880C93C041D5ECAB871549F16A5D) of the next version, since they've added a lot of new features.

Comment: It is pretty nice so far, but I can't seem to find the way to debug it. I tried to read some articles about debugging in it, but they all were about version 1.0.1 (and I downloaded 1.0.2) and all the necessary steps are kind of non-existent now. Not that I can make it work in netbeans :). I will take my time to see how much I really like this IDE.

Comment: I use XDebug. Works fine. I find it easier to let PHPStorm simply listen for incoming connections from the browser cookie.